# Firefox mising the right inch of it's window after waking from hibernate in 23.04

Tags: firefox, 23.04

After waking up from hibernation the right side of my Firefox window is gone. Looks like it's off-screen but you can't get to it.  Everything to the right of the minimize icon is missing.  I have to quit Firefox and relaunch after every hibernate.  Just started after upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04.

Comment: is FF full screen or minimised? Try clicking on the FF title bar to cycle between full screen and minimised and [edit] your question with the result.

Comment: This is Firefox full screen on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Looks like this resolved itself.  But now every time I try to drag a single firefox tab to a second monitor gnome crashes and I have to login again.